# Why does sp_rename not affect the output of sp_helptext?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
create procedure Eg_Proce
as
begin
select * from po;
end

go

exec sp_rename 'Eg_Proce','Example_Procedure'
```

After renaming procedure

```
sp_helptext 'Example_Procedure'
```

The definition of the procedure is not updated

```
create procedure Eg_Proce  
as  
begin  
select * from po;  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why but it is kind of documented.

[sp_rename (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

> Renaming a stored procedure, function, view, or trigger will not
>   change the name of the corresponding object name in the definition
>   column of the sys.sql_modules catalog view.

`sys.sql_modules` is a view that uses the base table `sys.sysschobjs`. `sp_helptext` uses the view `syscomments` that in turn uses the base table `sys.sysschobjs`.

Comment: It's easy to see why, the captured input that created the module would have to be updated to change the definition. There are many dragons under that bridge, the task is significantly more complex than a string replace. And the result would be a lie.